# I want to save cart details of my Ecommerce app into local storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, local-storage, e-commerce

I want to save cart details of my Ecommerce app in local storage sqfite... Currently whenever a user clicks on add to cart option icon it creates a new document in firebase with all the details. Can I do it on local storage. If yes please let me know how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local database. Try [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_ffi) or [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive). You need basic database knowledge to create a SQL/no SQL database.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but how will i save the item image that is save in FIrebase in the local database :(

Comment: I have seen some tutorial there an image is selcted from Gallery and then upload but here i need to save the image that is in server... How can i do that

Comment: @RetartedCoder You can get the image from your server, then convert that image into a BASE64 string and store that in the database. You can also just save the downloaded image into a folder.